# How should we structure our SVN environment for Agile/Scrum development with multiple teams when we have to share the same QA environment?

Tags: svn, version-control, continuous-integration, agile, scrum

I have been tasked with coming up with a svn structure for our transition to Agile that has to scale to multiple teams (with multiple developers). After talking to my colleagues I had come up with the example structure seen below. I got a little bit of push back from other team members with legit concerns. I was hoping find out the best practices for having a svn structure among multiple teams when we all have to share a QA environment.

[image: Proposed SVN structure]

In my example above, you can see that I have used a lot of Agile/Scrum terms. I did this to help explain my decisions in why I came up with this structure. Essentially the "main" trunk will always only have stories from all teams that have met "definition of done" which includes QA. The main problem pointed out to me was that we have to share environments (and for reasons, we can't virtualize these environments) and because of this, releasing daily for QA testing would be hard as each team would be stepping over each other. Another issue they wanted addressed was that some did not want each developer to have their own branch as it would increase the amount of merging each team/individual would have to do.

At this point I am not sure what to do our how to respond. I was hoping that some people/teams out here in SO land could tell us how they have theirs structured and what issues you have encountered because of your structure.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you take a look at "Continuous Delivery" by Jez Humble and David Farley. They go in to a lot of detail about branching strategies and talk specifically about SVN.

Are you pushing towards frequent releases? If you are, then the best approach would often be to have all the teams commiting in to the trunk. The only time to branch would be on a release, so that you can immediately fix production issues without worrying about the impact of in-progress work.

You might think this will lead to a lot of integration problems and you would be right. But the idea is to draw out integration issues at the earliest possible opportunity, which is typically the time when the effort to fix them is the lowest.

You would need to have in place some strong continuous integration to support this approach. Preferably with good automated regression test coverage.

Comment: We may intend on frequent releases. We are still working out those kind of details. I believe we are leaning towards releasing after a couple of sprints per team.

Comment: It's not easy to jump straight to a continuous delivery approach. But I would definitely recommend restricting the number of branches you do in SVN. If you do decide to branch, consider having continuous integration run against the branches as well as against the trunk. It is also worth automating regular merges from the trunk in to the branches, so that the branches do not diverge too far and create merge issues further down the line.

Comment: I never thought to even leverage auto-merging. That was a concern, that we would all be doing too much merging. If things were to trickle down automatically to each developers branch daily, I think they would be more accepting of my proposal.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you consider the following agile issues:

1. The QA role must be a member of your team (a senior developer preferably interested in software quality). Otherwise, the QA would be seen as an external service, so it is not much agile (see 'Extreme Programming Explained' by Kent Beck).
2. The Scrum Master should enforce the fact that working with branches is not a problem but a solution precisely for this situations in which there are a number of developers.
3. Working with a set of developers means that the Scrum Master has to be assure every module is well-developed. To do so, TDD (Test Driven Development) is a good strategy to get reports such as code coverage, check-style, copy+paste code (CPD) and cyclomatic complexity index (among others).
4. The Scrum Master should also consider to define a continuous integration strategy to assure every application module changes don't modify the expected behaviour of the current version or candidate release.

Agile approach does not only either a good source code strategy or management; the entire team has to be well-oriented, well-synchronized and well-motivated. Otherwise, your project would be a success but not agile.